# How to `pause`, and `resume` download work?

Tags: python, binary, download

Usually, downloading a file from the server is something like this:

```
fp = open(file, 'wb')
req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
for line in req:
    fp.write(line)
fp.close()
```

During downloading, the download process just has to be finished. If the process is stopped or interrupted, the download process needs to start again. So, I would like to enable my program to pause and resume the download, how do I implement such? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The web server must support `Range` request header to allow pause/resume download:

```
Range: <unit>=<range-start>-<range-end>
```

Then the client can make a request with the `Range` header if he/she wants to retrieve the specified bytes, for example:

```
Range: bytes=0-1024
```

In this case the server can respond with a `200 OK` indicating that it doesn't support `Range` requests,
Or it can respond with `206 Partial Content` like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1024
Content-Range: bytes 64-512/1024

Response body.... till 512th byte of the file
```

See:

- [Range request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range)
- [Content-Range response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Range)
- [Accept-Ranges response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Ranges)
- [206 Partial Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/206)
- [HTTP 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)

Answer (score 2):

In python, you can do:

```python
import urllib, os

class myURLOpener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    """Create sub-class in order to overide error 206.  This error means a
       partial file is being sent,
       which is ok in this case.  Do nothing with this error.
    """
    def http_error_206(self, url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers, data=None):
        pass

loop = 1
dlFile = "2.6Distrib.zip"
existSize = 0
myUrlclass = myURLOpener()
if os.path.exists(dlFile):
    outputFile = open(dlFile,"ab")
    existSize = os.path.getsize(dlFile)
    #If the file exists, then only download the remainder
    myUrlclass.addheader("Range","bytes=%s-" % (existSize))
else:
    outputFile = open(dlFile,"wb")

webPage = myUrlclass.open("http://localhost/%s" % dlFile)

#If the file exists, but we already have the whole thing, don't download again
if int(webPage.headers['Content-Length']) == existSize:
    loop = 0
    print "File already downloaded"

numBytes = 0
while loop:
    data = webPage.read(8192)
    if not data:
        break
    outputFile.write(data)
    numBytes = numBytes + len(data)

webPage.close()
outputFile.close()

for k,v in webPage.headers.items():
    print k, "=", v
print "copied", numBytes, "bytes from", webPage.url
```

You can find the source: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/83208-resuming-download-of-a-file/

It only works for http dls